# How to do something similar to C# Invoke() in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'm writing a project with Delphi. I need to do something to do the function that the `Invoke` method in C# does. I saw the `Synchronize()` method do this somewhere, but I don't know exactly how to write it. How can I do it ?

C# code:

```cs
private void ListenerOnDataTransmit(DataTransmitEventArgs e)
{
    transmittedMsg = BitConverter.ToString(e.TransmittedBytes, 0, e.TransmittedBytes.Length);

    //I want to write here 
    try { Invoke(new EventHandler(UpdateTransmittedMessagesListView)); }
    catch { }
}

// UpdateTransmittedMessagesListView 
public void UpdateTransmittedMessagesListView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    item.SubItems.Add(transmittedMsg);
    lvTransmittedMessages.Items.Insert(0, item);
    if (lvTransmittedMessages.Items.Count > 100)
        lvTransmittedMessages.Items.Clear();
}

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();   
    plistener.OnDataTransmit += new DataTransmitEventHandler(ListenerOnDataTransmit);
}
```

The codes are like this, I want to do the operations on the `Invoke` line in the first function.

Comment: You are correct, you call `Synchronize` to invoke code on the main thread.

Comment: What should I write as a parameter to the Synchronize () method?

Comment: You need to pass a method or an anon that captures whatever it is that you want to happen on the main thread. I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, the `Invoke()` method "*Executes a delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle*".

In Delphi, UI controls are (supposed to be) owned by the main UI thread.  You can use the [`TThread.Synchronize()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) or [`TThread.Queue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) method to execute code from a worker thread in the context of the main UI thread, eg:

```pascal
type
  TWorkerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FData: string;
    procedure DoUpdate;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
begin
  ...
  FData := ...;
  Synchronize(DoUpdate);
  ...
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.DoUpdate;
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := MyForm.lvTransmittedMessages.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption := DateTimeToStr(Now);
  Item.SubItems.Add(FData);
  if MyForm.lvTransmittedMessages.Items.Count > 100 then
    MyForm.lvTransmittedMessages.Items.Clear;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
procedure SomeWorkerThreadProc;
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := ...;

  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    var
      Item: TListItem;
    begin
      Item := MyForm.lvTransmittedMessages.Items.Add;
      Item.Caption := DateTimeToStr(Now);
      Item.SubItems.Add(s);
      if MyForm.lvTransmittedMessages.Items.Count > 100 then
        MyForm.lvTransmittedMessages.Items.Clear;
    end
  );
end;
```